# How to Manipulate Button in OnCreate To Get Lat Lng

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-studio

I understand that this Question has been asked in several versions, and so many varieties but I still can't get the concept of Google Maps API.

I created a Button button1 on the MAP Fragment which when clicked should create a Marker on the Location my **Blue Dot** is. But I can't get the Lat Lng values in the `OnCreate()`

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        checkLocationPermission();
    }
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);


    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Button Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

the `onLocationChanged` is working perfectly it keeps showing the **Blue Dot** as it is supposed to do - ok I have a problem of keeping the dot in center - but thats my homework to fulfill.

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    mLastLocation = location;


    if (mCurrLocationMarker != null) {
        mCurrLocationMarker.remove();
    }

    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());

    //Place current location marker
    //MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
    //markerOptions.position(latLng);
    //markerOptions.title("فتحت البرنامج هنا");
    //markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN));
    //mCurrLocationMarker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

    //move map camera
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(18));

    if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
    }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated, I am new in Java Android world, and trying to self learn, well not this time :-)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this (if I've understood your question):

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if (mCurrLocationMarker != null) {
            mCurrLocationMarker.remove();
        }

        if (mLastLocation != null) {
            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(mLastLocation.getLatitude(), mLastLocation.getLongitude());

            //Place current location marker
            MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
            markerOptions.position(latLng);
            markerOptions.title("فتحت البرنامج هنا");
            markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN));
            mCurrLocationMarker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
        }
    }
});
```

---

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    mLastLocation = location;

    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());

    //move map camera
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(18));

    if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you @stefan that's exactly what I needed. I guess reading so many answers and solutions made me loose the basics. Hvala Kolega